# Explaining information in log file

Tags: logging

I searched the web for detailed information about log files with name=value information like :
SRC=192.168.1.1 SPT=443 DST=192.168.1.2 DPT=50000 etc.. but I couldn't find information about all of them.
Can someone help me with explaining this 2 rows :

IN=eth0 OUT=eth1 SRC=192.168.1.2 DST=192.168.1.3 LEN=81 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=13383 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=48000 DPT=447 WINDOW=254 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0

AND

IN=eth0 OUT=eth1 SRC=192.168.1.2 DST=192.168.1.3 LEN=215 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=5786 PROTO=UDP SPT=49679 DPT=53 LEN=195

I need help explaining what IN, OUT, LEN, TOS, PREC and ID mean and most importantly why I have two different LENs in the second row (LEN=215 and LEN=195)